# Conditionally execute command in Linux shell script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I use Cordova CLI to create Android APKs on my Ubuntu 16.04 VPS server.  Once the APK has been built I copy it to Dropbox on local machine and then install the APK on my Android test devices.  I want to use the Dropbox API to upload the APK directly so I avoid the unnecessary 3 way transfer:

```
Server -> Local Machine -> Dropbox -> Android test device.
```

The sequence of operations would go like this

- Shell scripts (already written) on the server cleanup the Android source and rebuild the APK
- This is done with Phonegap/Cordova verbose output on which ensures that a successful build emits the following text at the end

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

```
 Total time: 5.495 secs
 Built the following apk(s): 
 /path/to/app/source/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk


No scripts found for hook "after_compile".


No scripts found for hook "after_build".


[36m[phonegap][39m completed 'cordova build android -d --no-telemetry'
```

The final step - uploading the android apk to my Dropbox should only be done if BUILD SUCCESSFUL is found in the Cordova/Phonegap debug output.  I have got everything in place but I am not sure how I should check for BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Here is the pseudocode in the shell script

```
!# /bin/bash
pgclean;
# pgclean is another shell script that cleans up the Phonegap project in the 
# current folder
pgbuild;
# this rebuilds the APK and saves the detailed debug output to
# /path/to/my/project/debug.txt
# it is debug.txt which would contain BUILD SUCCESSFUL etc
```

Here is where my knowledge of bash scripts hits the buffers.  What I would like to do next:

- Test debug.txt, above, to ensure that the build is successful
- If so call my final shell script

  moveapktodropbox $1

where $1 is the parameter I pass to the current shell script to provide the name under which the APK should be stored in Dropbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With POSIX every program should exit with a status code: **0** means *success*, **1** *warning*, **2** and more *error*.

You could test if the process build exit with status code 0.

```
buildprocess
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then otherscript ; fi
```

**$?** means *last status code*

or more concise:

```
buildprocess && otherscript
```

Comment: Thank you for this - not what I did in the end but it adds to my knowledge anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually ended up doing this

```
x=$(grep -c "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" /path/to/my/app/debug.txt);
if [ $x -eq 1 ]; then
 moveit $1;
 echo "Good Build";
 exit;
fi;
```